# How to send shell script (json) output to aws sns topic?

Tags: json, shell, amazon-web-services, sh, amazon-sns

I have a created an arn topic in AWS console, also created subscription using email and confirmed the subscription.

I have an EC2 instance running in AWS, I wrote a small script to send some details like, type of instance, Operating System used, architecture, JDK installed and formatted it to "json" using "printf" command.

I want to send that json output of the script to the topic I created. The plan is to automate the stuff in future, but for now its just a testing purpose.

**Code I'm trying:**

```
#/bin/bash
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xUISTaZscgstTgsreTTS
AWS_SECRET_KEY=8hsggTjakjst86AHGSR98agHHYI
credentials="-I $AWS_ACCESS_KEY -S $AWS_SECRET_KEY"
topicARN=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:9876577867654:xyzsy-ex:9d18e516-25h3-81h1-n148-chqa712qi1p0
json="$(./temp.sh)"
aws sns publish --topic-arn $topicARN --message-structure json --message "${json}"
```

**temp.sh output:**

```
{
    "component": {
        "component": "xyz-name",
        "comp_version": "03"
    },
    "Instance": {
        "Instance_Type": "t2.small",
        "Instance_ID": "i-1e993001234q56789"
        "operatingsystem": "rhel"
    },
    "JDK": "1.8.0_111"
}
```

But it's asking to provide AWS region and if provided complaining about credentials validity. Is a there a way to provide credentials dynamically rather setting shell to pick from ".aws/config"?

I'm planning to run it as cronjob so that the output will be sent to topic every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html):

> The AWS CLI looks for credentials and configuration settings in the
>   following order:
>
> - Command Line Options – region, output format and profile can be specified as command options to override default settings.
> - Environment Variables – `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, etc.
> - The AWS credentials file – located at `~/.aws/credentials` on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\credentials` on Windows.
>     This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition to a default
>     profile.
> - The CLI configuration file – typically located at `~/.aws/config` on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at `C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\config` on
>     Windows. This file can contain a default profile, named profiles, and
>     CLI specific configuration parameters for each.
> - Instance profile credentials – these credentials can be used on EC2 instances with an assigned instance role, and are delivered through
>     the Amazon EC2 metadata service.

So, you can pass the credentials from the `aws sns` command that you invoke:

```
#/bin/bash
topicARN=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:9876577867654:xyzsy-ex:9d18e516-25h3-81h1-n148-chqa712qi1p0
json="$(./temp.sh)"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xUISTaZscgstTgsreTTS AWS_SECRET_KEY=8hsggTjakjst86AHGSR98agHHYI aws sns publish --topic-arn $topicARN --message-structure json --message "${json}"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried your solution. Its no more asking for credentials, however still complaining for region.

'You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".'

I even tried to append region just like credentials, still it didn't work.

Comment: @KrishnaGhantaChowdary For region, you need to pass the `--region` paramter to the command: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xUISTaZscgstTgsreTTS AWS_SECRET_KEY=8hsggTjakjst86AHGSR98agHHYI aws sns publish --topic-arn $topicARN --message-structure json --message "${json}" --region ap-south-1`

Comment: WOW... I did some trail and error.. It just worked.. Now I get some error message: 

An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: Message Structure - No default entry in JSON message body

Comment: @KrishnaGhantaChowdary Your `$json` is faulty :)

Comment: Well thanks for explanation. when I tried to validate the JSON output I got from script, it shows its a valid JSON. Can we directly push JSON object to sns topic?

Comment: In case you are still figuring out, you have to embed the message inside the top-level SON object named default. @KrishnaGhantaChowdary
from docs https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sns/publish.html

"the value of the Message parameter must:

be a syntactically valid JSON object; and

contain at least a top-level JSON key of “default” with a value that is a string."